# Cannot start VMware, gets stuck at 'waiting for connection'

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

I am running VMWare Workstation 15 on Elementay OS (Ubuntu 18). After creating a new virtual machine when I start the machine, there's a message screen that says 'waiting for connection' and it stays like that forever. Screenshot below:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUAR1.jpg)

VMware UI Log:

https://pastebin.com/raw/beN409im

(text is too large to be pasted here)

Comment: Monospaced log output should be able to be placed within a code box...  Use the three backtick method, with an example being on the formatting bar - Click the ? mark > click Code > backticks are the second option, with the content beginning "Markdown and HTML...".  If it's still too long, use a text editor's _replace all_ option to remove arbitrary, non-essential info, such as `2019-10-22T` and `+05:00`